# The further you move away VS The further away you move

Tags: comparative-constructions

I am sorry for asking. There are plenty of similar questions and I know the structure of `the more... the more`:

> The + Comparative + Subject + Verb

But I want to make sure that I write correctly.
Which sentence is correct:

1. The more users register, the further you move away from the beginning.
2. The more users register, the further away you move from the beginning.
3. The more users register, the further away from the beginning you move.

My opinion, the first is correct.

Answer (score 1):

All three are correct depending on the context and the intended emphasis of the writer. But Yes, I would consider the 1. the default answer, and correct in nearly all circumstances.
2. would be the least correct but usable in cases where you want to emphasize the movement
  3. would be correct in many cases and useful if you want to emphasize the fact that the movement is away from the place of origin.

Comment: I think you should have stuck with "all three are correct" and left it at that.